# SvelteKit/Prisma string replacement

Tags: mysql, typescript, prisma, sveltekit

I am creating a project using SvelteKit, Prisma, TypeScript, and MYSQL.

In this project, I have a path "/spellbooks/[spellbookName]", where the spellbookName can be any string (i.e., spellbookName might be "User's Spellbook"). Since I don't want to include an apostrophe in the URL param, I am redirecting the user to something like "/spellbooks/users-spellbook" instead of "/spellbooks/user's-spellbook".

In my +page.server.ts file, I am getting the spellbookName value from the url and replacing the dashes with spaces, which leaves me with a value like "users spellbook", but when I go to search the database with prisma.findFirst I can't find the spellbook by its name since it doesn't include the apostrophe. Is there any way I could search my DB with Prisma to find a result where the name is equal to the name stored in the database just without the apostrophe?

Here is what I have so far in my +page.server.ts file along with my Prisma schema:

**+page.server.ts**

```
import { prisma } from '$lib/server/prisma';
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const GET: RequestHandler = async ({ params }) => {
    const spellbookName = params.spellbookName?.replace(/-/g, ' ');
    const spellbook = await prisma.spellbook.findFirst({
        where: {
            spellbook_name: {
                equals: spellbookName
            }
        },
        include: {
            spells: {
                include: {
                    classes: true,
                    components: true,
                    description_list: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (!spellbook) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: `Spellbook '${spellbookName}' not found` }), {
            status: 404
        });
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(spellbook), { status: 200 });
};
```

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model AuthUser {
  id           String        @id @unique
  username     String        @unique
  role         Role          @default(USER)
  auth_key     AuthKey[]
  auth_session AuthSession[]
  spellbooks   Spellbook[]

  @@map("user")
}

model AuthSession {
  id             String   @id @unique
  user_id        String
  active_expires BigInt
  idle_expires   BigInt
  auth_user      AuthUser @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@index([user_id])
  @@map("session")
}

model AuthKey {
  id              String   @id @unique
  hashed_password String?
  user_id         String
  primary_key     Boolean
  expires         BigInt?
  auth_user       AuthUser @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@index([user_id])
  @@map("key")
}

model Spell {
  id                Int                        @id @default(autoincrement())
  level             Int
  spell_name        String                     @unique
  classes           SpellClass[]
  components        SpellComponent[]
  spell_description String                     @db.VarChar(5000)
  description_list  SpellDescriptionListItem[]
  description_more  String?                    @db.VarChar(5000)
  duration          String
  range             String
  school            String
  source            String
  subdescription    String?                    @db.VarChar(1000)
  time              String
  spellbooks        Spellbook[]                @relation("SpellToSpellbook")

  @@map("spell")
}

model SpellClass {
  id       Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  spell_id Int
  spell    Spell @relation(fields: [spell_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  class    Class

  @@index(spell_id)
  @@map("spell_class")
}

model SpellComponent {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  spell_id  Int
  spell     Spell  @relation(fields: [spell_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  component String

  @@index(spell_id)
  @@map("spell_component")
}

model SpellDescriptionListItem {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  spell_id    Int
  spell       Spell  @relation(fields: [spell_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  description String @db.VarChar(1000)

  @@index(spell_id)
  @@map("spell_description_list")
}

model Spellbook {
  id                    Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_id               String
  spellbook_name        String   @unique
  character_name        String
  spellbook_description String?  @db.VarChar(1000)
  class                 Class
  image_url             String
  created_at            DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at            DateTime @updatedAt
  auth_user             AuthUser @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  spells                Spell[]  @relation("SpellToSpellbook")

  @@index([user_id])
  @@map("spellbook")
}

enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}

enum Class {
  Artificer
  Bard
  Cleric
  Druid
  Paladin
  Ranger
  Sorcerer
  Warlock
  Wizard
}
```

I have tried using the Prisma "contains" syntax instead of using "equals" but that did not work.

Can provide more code or a link to my GitHub repo if that would help more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Prisma's documentation on filter conditions and operators](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-conditions-and-operators), there's nothing that could allow you to ignore punctuation while matching.

Unfortunately, you'll have to resort to a Javascript [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the result:

```js
import { prisma } from '$lib/server/prisma';
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const GET: RequestHandler = async ({ params }) => {
    const spellbookName = params.spellbookName?.replace(/-/g, ' ');
    const spellbooks = await prisma.spellbook.findMany({
        where: {},
        include: {
            spells: {
                include: {
                    classes: true,
                    components: true,
                    description_list: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    const spellbook = spellbooks.find(spellbook => 
        spellbook.spellbook_name.replace(/'/g, '').toLowerCase() === spellbookName.toLowerCase()
    )

    if (!spellbook) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: `Spellbook '${spellbookName}' not found` }), {
            status: 404
        });
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(spellbook), { status: 200 });
};
```

I also turn both values into lowercase before comparing them to ensure that punctuation does not matter.

A more performant approach would be to store the apostrophe-less name in a separate database field, such as `spellbook_slug`, and matching on that.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of the more performant approach, added a slug field to my db and its working perfectly now! Thank you so much for the suggestion!